# Android 9-patch images don't stretch correctly

Tags: android, png, nine-patch

I have the exact same problem as this guy, only the solutions proposed don't work for me.

[my 9 Patch Image stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934689/my-9-patch-image-stopped-working)

In eclipse, my 9-patches look as they should, but when running the app on my device, they stretch like a normal png-image.

I just updated to the latest sdk version, then I tried the fix proposed in the question linked above, but it didn't help.

Is there anyone else who has the same problem, and for whom the mentioned fix doesn't help?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Android How to use 9 patch png](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-how-to-use-9-patch-png.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my happy comment in April, the error reappeared after some image manipulation. Then I got it working by redrawing the image borders. I now believe that the problem was that one (or more) of the pixels on the border was not completely transparent. I find it odd, though, that the compiler doesn't react on that, the file suffix was .9.png, after all... And I don't understand why it was shown correctly in the eclipse preview.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that you ARE using the very latest SDK (r17), and then do a full, clean rebuild of your project.

I've seen this issue many times, but even when the SDK bug was there a full rebuild would fix it. Since r17 I've not seen it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I did use the latest sdk. Using clean and then build in eclipse did not help. After several attempts I finally got it working by removing the image, performing a clean build, then putting the image back and clean-building again. It seems eclipse doesn't do a completely clean rebuild when you just use clean and rebuild.

Comment: I use IntelliJ, which seems to be fine after a full rebuild. It might work to delete all the outputs of the build process - gen, out, production, target etc. Delete everything except the source. I expect that would have the same effect as your solution.