# Why won't Android Eclipse project update graphics?

Tags: android, nine-patch

After a month of development, my project has suddenly decide to refuse to update my button graphic. I took my existing 9patch button and brightened it a little, saved it, and now it won't update on my device. Eclipse shows the new graphic (eventually) but the device rendition is the old button. I have to manually Clean, but in doing so my 9patch has broken and doesn't scale. I've read [my 9 Patch Image stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934689/my-9-patch-image-stopped-working) and included the jar, but still the 9patch I'm trying to change won't update on my device, or it updates as a standard fixed-sized image with the black 9patch markings showing. If I delete the 9patch from resources and replace it with another button, it works.

Basically it's as if my project has gotten hokey. I've used Clean... and resource Refresh repeatedly, but it's not playing well. Once it even said I had manually edited the R.java file after a Clean... Is there some super cleanup reset thing I can do?

tldr; When I change graphic, the new graphic isn't updated on device. I use refresh and Project/Clean but that breaks the 9patch. What's wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the special _9-patch_ areas are not transparent, and consist entirely of either black or white, otherwise it fails in some systems...

Comment: There was something wrong with the 9patch. Dunno what, but the 9patch tool didn't show the black areas so I redid it.